# How to display data from Database after selecting a row from Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I have a Databound Gridview with HyperLinkField to view the row information redirected to the next page. The columns displayed in the Gridview is only a small part in my Database and i want the whole Database data including those not shown on the GridView to be displayed onto the next page.

I have tried using the `DataNavigateUrlFields` but this will only display records that are in the GridView.

Here are some parts of my code

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvStock" CssClass="GV" runat="server" enablepagingandcallbackz="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="OnSorting" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"  PageSize="20" BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:HyperLinkField Text="View" DataNavigateUrlFields="pCode,pID,bCode,SBrand,SDescription,sCost,sPrice,SType,sSupplierName,sSupplierDirect" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetail.aspx?pCode={0}&pID={1}&bCode={2}&SBrand={3}&SDescription={4}&sCost={5}&sPrice={6}&SType={7}&sSupplierName={8}&sSupplierDirect={9}"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pCode" HeaderText="Product Code" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="pID" HeaderText="PID"/>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind

```
protected void gvStock_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string id = gvStock.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            Response.Redirect("ProductDetail.aspx?");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you one Example...so, you can easily understand....apply Your Logic...in Your Code...

**.aspx Page**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTesting" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="98%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Number">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkTest" runat="server" Text='<% # Bind("Test") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("Test") %>'
                            OnClick="lnkTest_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<% # Bind("Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**.aspx.cs Page**

```
protected void lnkTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent;
        HiddenField hdnId = (HiddenField)gvr.FindControl("hdnId");

    if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="1")
    {
            Response.Redirect("frmTest1.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }

    else if(Convert.ToString(hdnId.value)=="2")
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest2.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("frmTest.aspx?Id=" + Convert.ToString(hdnId.Value), false);
    }
    }
```

**Note:-**

In Page Load,you have to bind GridView(as per your Prefrence..)

Suppose,You have a Gridview with Link Button(which redirect to different Pages...)

So, you have to also bind Id........so can Redirect to Different Pages as Per your ID...

On click of link button you can redirect to other page(as per your Logic..) with sending Query string value(Id)

I'm using asp.net with c# 4.5

Comment: when i click on the LinkButton , it doesnt redirect to anywhere.